# How to check a Node exist or not in response from retrofit in Android?

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, retrofit2

I am getting two responses for a api request for login.if the credentials are correct i get the response as

```
{
    "name": "Dheepak",
    "email": "Email"
}
```

If the credentials are not valid then i get

```
{
    "status": "False"
}
```

I am getting `null poitner exception` in either of case.What i want is i want to check if a field named  "status" exist or not in my response.How can i check it?If its a normal json there has a provision for using .has();
I am using retrofit.Please help1!!

Here is the response

```
 @Override
public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {


    if(response.body().getStatus().equals(null)){
        Toast.makeText(mActivity,"No User Exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }else {

        String name = response.body().getName();
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Please add sample source code

Comment: @Noufal, Check my answer it will help to get rid of dynamic response :)

Answer (score 2):

**One way**

Use `optString` in `JSONObject`.Edited in your `onResponse` method.
    // edited here ,add toJson

```
String jsonResponse = new Gson().toJson(result);
// String responseString = response.body().toString();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse );
String status = jsonObject.optString("status");
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(status)) {
    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "No User Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
    Toast.makeText(mActivity, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Another way**

I changed the `JSONObject` to `Map` and got the map's size.

Then according the size,we can judge the response.

Edited in your `onResponse` method.

**Try this**

```
try {
    // edited here ,add toJson
    String jsonResponse = new Gson().toJson(result);
    // String responseString = response.body().toString();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse );
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    Iterator<String> sIterator = jsonObject.keys();
    while (sIterator.hasNext()) {
        // get key
        String key = sIterator.next();
        // get value
        String value = jsonObject.getString(key);
        map.put(key, value);
        System.out.println("key: " + key + ",value：" + value);
    }
    if (map.size() == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "No User Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value LoginResponse@f018ea1 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Could you add log to show the `response.body().toString();`.?

Comment: Response<LoginResponse> response .Here the response will be in Class right?Is that why it cant convert to JSON?

Comment: You response is Class.

Comment: replace this --- public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response)  with public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {    and  replace -         String responseString = response.body().toString(); with         String responseString = response.body().String();

Comment: Thanks.It worked.Iterator part works but dont need to I just used has ..             String jsonResponse = new Gson().toJson(response.body());
            // String responseString = response.body().toString();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse );
            if(jsonObject.has("name")){
                String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
 Toast.makeText(mActivity, "No User Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Could you solve your question? I had a meeting just now.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the response to the JsonObject and use **has()** method to figure out if the response has that particular field or not.

```
                String responseStg=response.body().toString();
                try {
                    JSONObject responseObj= new JSONObject(responseStg);
                    if(responseObj.has("status")){
                      //Something
                    }else{
                      //Something else
                    }    
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know may be i am late but here is tricky solution for a dynamic response in Retrofit

**1. Create a MODEL class or this**

```
{
    "name": "Dheepak",
    "email": "Email"
}
```

**2. Create Second Model Class for Error i.e LoginError**

```
{
    "status": "False"
}
```

**3. Define your API Call method like :**

```
@GET("your url")
Call<Object> getLogin();
```

**And finally**

```
  Call<Object> call =  // call here your API and implement CallBack Method

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {

            if(response instanceof FIRSTMODELCLASS){
               // your response

           }else{
               // your error 
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```